# How can I troubleshoot the issue of Airflow jobs getting unexpectedly terminated after migration?

Tags: pyspark, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

let me explain Airflow upgradation and migration story here.
I am using airflow `version 1.10.3` with python `2.7 version` to run my shell scripts, Apache Spark jobs etc. All jobs are working fine in current airflow version.

I recently started upgrading the airflow to latest stable airflow `version 2.6.3` on Python `3.8 version` and set up 2 node airflow cluster on two different Linux server.

Also, have set up all the dependencies python packages, jars, configuration files etc.

Now, When I am running jobs from new airflow, the job is getting terminated with AirflowException.  Here is the details exception.

```
[2023-07-14, 09:21:42 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:271} WARNING - Recorded pid 24036 does not match the current pid 24058
[2023-07-14, 09:21:42 UTC] {process_utils.py:131} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to group 24058. PIDs of all processes in the group: [24324, 24327, 24340, 24341, 24342, 24351, 24352, 24353, 24354, 24058]
[2023-07-14, 09:21:42 UTC] {process_utils.py:86} INFO - Sending the signal Signals.SIGTERM to group 24058
[2023-07-14, 09:21:42 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1517} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2023-07-14, 09:21:42 UTC] {subprocess.py:104} INFO - Sending SIGTERM signal to process group
[2023-07-14, 09:21:42 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1824} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 201, in execute
    result = self.subprocess_hook.run_command(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/hooks/subprocess.py", line 91, in run_command
    for raw_line in iter(self.sub_process.stdout.readline, b""):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1519, in signal_handler
    raise AirflowException("Task received SIGTERM signal")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal
[2023-07-14, 09:21:42 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1345} INFO - Marking task as FAILED
```

To solve above issue tried below option.

Disabled mini schedular : `schedule_after_task_execution = False`

dagrun_timeout : this set to 1360 min

Any suggestions or assistance provided in addressing this issue would be greatly appreciated.